# Don't give Informed badge if user hasn't fully read About page

Tags: feature-request, badges, tour, informed-badge

I've just looked through [About page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) for several seconds. After that I got [Informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2600/informed) - "Read the entire about page". But it's not true - I've only scrolled it from top to bottom.

I propose to measure the amount of time that user spent in each section. It should be at least 3 seconds to get the badge.

Comment: Do you really want users to spend more time on that abomination of a page?

Answer (score 14):

There's no real sure-fire way of making sure somewhere reads all of it. You can add in complicated things, like making users click-to-expand every section of the FAQ, but that still doesn't really guarantee anything. All it guarantees is they know how to click their mouse.

If people really don't want to read it, they're not going to read it. All the badge really does is get the user to the page so they know about it, and *encourage* them to look it over.

Comment: Well, we could add a couple of multiple choice tests.

Comment: The solution is obviously SURPRISE TESTS. (Edit: Gamecat beat me to the punch)

Comment: How about annual exams ? :)

Comment: Strikes me that if they know enough about the site to be going in search of specific badges, it might be a tad late to be reading the about page...